# Display SVG image in razor view ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, svg, razor

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application and I want to display an SVG image inside my razor view I tried everything but it did not work , I can easily display ".png" or any other format but it doesn't work with ".SVG" extension.
 what is the correct way display an SVG image in Razor??

Answer (score 2):

I know of two good options.

In all the modern browsers you can display an SVG file with the standard `<IMG>` tag just like a png file.  If you want to treat the SVG like an image then this is the way to go. 
The only real difference is that you will often need to specify the size of the image since SVG images are scalable.  Also, you sometimes have to specify the color you want to use for the SVG image if it does not have embedded colors.  Most of the time SVG icons or smaller flat images omit the color so you can specify it with CSS instead.

It should look something like this:

```
<style>
    #myImg { 
        height:100px; 
        width:100px; 
        color:black;
        background-color:white;
    } 
</style>

<img id="myImg" src="Areas_icon.svg" />
```

You can also embed the SVG file directly in the HTML output using the `<SVG>` tag.  In this case, you would need to open the SVG file on the server using a file stream (or similar) then write the textual content of the file into the Razor view's response.  If your SVG is an interactive application element then you need to take this route.  This is a good candidate for an HTML Helper.

You can see [Mozilla Docs on Inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Set in css file backgroud 
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"svg to base64 conversion code"